# Testing room migration, Cannot find the schema file in the assets folder [room-migration]

Tags: android, android-room

This issue came after I decided to add another entity to the room database. The schema is being exported in the expected directory. All build.gradle setting is done and seems to be working but is not. Since I got:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find the schema file in the assets folder. Make sure to include the exported json schemas in your test assert inputs. 
See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema for details. Missing file: com.company.companyapp.db.AppStore/1.json
```

In fact both json schemas are being generated but the test runner is not able to find such files.
Here is the gradle setup:

```
testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true

defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/store".toString()]
        }
    }

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
    android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
}

sourceSets {
    androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/store".toString())
}

dependencies {
    def roomVersion = '2.2.1'
    // Other deps ...
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$testCoreVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$extJUnitVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$testCoreVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$extJUnitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
}
```

I also note the Studio IDE marks the json schema directory holder
[image]

By looking at the google room migration examples I can see there is a difference, and not talking about the name.
[image]

So it's very clear the gradle plugin is doing something different than I spect or the documentation says it should work, but it doesn't.

```
at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.loadSchema(MigrationTestHelper.java:320)
at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.createDatabase(MigrationTestHelper.java:152)
at com.company.companyapp.MigrationTest.migrate1To2(MigrationTest.java:32)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you manage to find the problem?

Answer (score 27):

Using this workaround found by [PaulWoitaschek](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3928#issuecomment-395309991) works for me with Robolectric 4.3:

add schemas dir on debug souceSets on your app's `build.gradle`

Groovy

```
    sourceSets {
        debug.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
```

Kotlin DSL

```
    sourceSets {
        getByName("debug").assets.srcDirs(files("$projectDir/schemas")) // Room
    }
```

Comment: Wroks perfect! Thanks for share!

Answer (score 1):

Please also make sure while creating the `MigrationTestHelper` to insert the actual `database.class`. I got confused and set my `Entity.class` instead, leading to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it in **android**:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                             "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then build the project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have both schemas exported under the schemas/ folder. For instance, if your testing the migration from version 1 to version 2, you must have both 1.json and 2.json files exported on the schemas/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error recently and found that it was caused by a change in package of my database class.

In order to resolve this you'll have to copy all json files from the old schema package location to the new one: Inside the schemas directory the migration files may be located in a subdirectory name **com.app.old.MyDB**. Copy all the json files into the subdirectory in the schemas folder example **com.app.new.MyDB** (You may need to create this directory).

The com.app... refers to the package name of your DB class.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
sourceSets {
   androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("store".toString())
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files-java.lang.Object...-), the argument is

> A CharSequence, including String or GString. Interpreted **relative** to the project directory, as per file(Object)

(emphasis mine)